# Generate random text based on form field

Tags: javascript, input, auto-generate

What I want to do in javascript is generate a random "code" based on text already entered in a field in a form.

What I have is a form, with a text input: name="youname"
Then, below this I have an input field: name="generated_ref"

What I would like to do, it when the user clicks on the "Generated Ref" field, is populate it with a ref, of 3 letters and 4 numbers.

Below is what I have already, but it used a-z rather than the data entered into the text field above

```
function makeref()
{
oFormObject = document.forms['newuser'];
oFormElement = oFormObject.elements["user[generated_ref]"];
var Stamp = new Date()
var hours = Stamp.getHours()
var mins = Stamp.getMinutes()
var text = "";
var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for( var i=0; i < 3; i++ ) //only allow 3 letters
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

oFormObject.elements["user[generated_ref]"].value = text + hours + mins;
}
```

You can see in the above code, I generate 3 letters from a-z and 4 numbers from the hour and minute of the current time.
What I want to do, is replace var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; with the text enters in "Your Name"

Hope this makes sense!
Andrew

Comment: Is the problem just getting the value typed into your text input?

Comment: More of less, yes. what I would like to do is replace the "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" with the text entered into "Your Name" but I'm unsure how to get this, because my previous attempts didn't work.

Comment: You tried use document.getElementById("<field>").value ?

Comment: @Edward - do I feel stupid! I was trying to use oFormObject.elements["user[yourname]"]; you're comment worked a treat!

Comment: @AndrewD old comment posted as answer; if it was right mark it as answer. Bye

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used javascript in a while, but I believe what you want is to take the input box and use:

```
var possible = inputbox.value
```

See if that works.

I'm a little confused though, because I don't see the code for a place to input the user text in there, though it might just be that I haven't used javascript in too long for me to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Previous comment posted as answer:

```
 document.getElementById("<field>").value
```